# Cant call function parameter by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change a H2 text, by clicking on an element and executing a function that will use jQuery to do the job. I don't know what is wrong, but its not recognizing my parameter 'x'.
Could you help me to find out what`s wrong?

```
function products(productName, productCode, productPrice, productImg) {
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productCode = productCode;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.productImg = productImg;
}

var product1 = new products("T-SHIRT", "FLF46465-M", "132$", "product1.jpg");  

$(document).ready(function(){  
    function productCode(x){
        $('h2').text(x['productName']); 
    };
});
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/6ayz681f/9/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1vvynodm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the function in Global scope outside document-ready handler.

And, Pass parameter without quotes, so that its treated as variable

```
<a class="clickme" href="#" onclick="productCode(product1)">click me</a>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1vvynodm/)